# Does RAM support limit the types of RAM that can be installed even if FSB indicates otherwise?

Tags: memory, speed, fsb

I'm thinking of upgrading the memory on my Toshiba Satellite A10 series laptop (psa10a-012nx). It currently houses PC2100 RAMs, but I'm wondering if I can improve the performance of my laptop by upgrading to PC2700 RAM. On reading the laptop's user manual, I noticed that it indicates that I should be using PC2100 DDR266 RAMs and yet the FSB is 400 Mhz. I did an analysis of the machine using the PC Wizard software and found the following information below.

```
NorthBridge Information :  
Architecture     : HUB 
Manufacturer     : Intel (Toshiba America Information Systems) 
Codename         : Montara 
Revision         : A1 
Bus Speed        : 99.8MHz 
FSB Frequency    : 399MHz (QDR) 
FSB max. Support : 400MHz 
RAM max. Support : DDR (266MHz)
```

According to the PC Wizard details, I think the machine's FSB speed is capable of handling higher speed RAM such as PC2700 DDR-333, but the machine's maximum possible support for RAM is 266MHz. I was under the impression that the FSB determines the data transfer rate of the RAM I can install, but based on the information from the user manual and PC Wizard previously mentioned, upgrading to a higer data transfer rate RAM, i.e. PC2700 DDR-333, would not give me more performance benefit over a PC2100 DDR266 RAM. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RAM clock and FSB are two different things.  You can install the faster memory, but if the motherboard only supports DDR266, you will not see any benefit from it.